# How to add fractions in Java

Tags: java, math, fractions

I am trying to make a simple program that adds two fractions.

```
    public static void add(int nom1, int denom1, int nom2, int denom2){

    int comd = denom1*denom2; //creates common denominator by multiplying both denominators

    int answer = nom1*nom2+nom1*nom2; //attempting to get answer (not working very well)

    System.out.println(nom1+"/"+denom1+" + "+nom2+"/"+denom2+" = "+answer+"/"+comd); // outputs   test like 1/2 + 4/8 = 8/8

    start(); // restarts the program
}
```

Unfortunately, my calculation to find the sum doesnt work, and i can not figure out another way of doing this. Thanks in advance for anyone who helps. Sorry if this seems noobish, but I can't find anything online that works that I can understand.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on math, but I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be: int answer = nom1*denom2 + nom2*denom1.

Comment: @jrahhali You should add that as an answer

Comment: As a general tip as well, you should use Eulers GCD algorithm to get the simplest form of the output.

Comment: Thanks to all you guys for the advice

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be:

```
int answer = nom1*denom2 + nom2*denom1;
```

instead of:

```
int answer = nom1*nom2+nom1*nom2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public static void add(int nom1, int denom1, int nom2, int denom2){

    int comd = denom1*denom2; //creates common denominator by multiplying both denominators

    int newNomAnswer = nom1*denom2 + nom2*denom1;


    System.out.println(nom1 + "/" + denom1 + " + " + nom2 + "/" + denom2 + " = " + newNomAnswer + "/" + comd);

    start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer by jrahhali is correct. My version scales nicely if you chose to add more than 2 fraction.

```
 int comd = denom1 * denom2;
 int answer = (comd/denom1 * nom1) + (comd/denom2 * nom2);

 System.out.println(nom1 + "/" + denom1 + " + " + nom2 + "/" + denom2 
                    + " = " + answer + "/" + comd);
```

> This is because I don't skip the division like he does.

Answer (score 0):

The way to add two fractions in Java is to first find the [Least Common Multiple (LCM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of the two denominators: denom = lcm(denom1, denom2). This is the denominator of the answer.

Then you find the nominator using the follwing formula: nom = denom/denom1*nom1 + denom/denom2*nom2.

Finally, you can simplify the fraction by dividing both the numerator and denomerator by their [Greatest Common Divisor (GCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor). Try it out [with this online widget](https://repo.progsbase.com/repoviewer/no.inductive.libraries/Fractions/0.1.5///Add).

Answer (score 0):

Try my code... this is adding similar and de similar fractions.

```
import java.util.*;


    public class Fractions {
    public static int firstMultiplier = 0;
    public static int secondMultiplier = 0;

    public Fractions() {
        
    }
    
    
    public static void addFrac(int oneNum,int oneDenum, int twoNum, int twoDenum) {
        // checks if the fractions are similar or de similar
        if(simDesimChecker(oneDenum,twoDenum)) {
            // adding similar fraction (fractions that have the same denominator)
            int x ,y;
            x = oneNum + twoNum;
            y = oneDenum;
            
            // this answerChecker() checks if the answer can simplify further
            answerChecker(x,y);
            
        }else {
            // adding de similar fraction (fractions that DOES NOT have the same denominator)
            
            // this numMultiplier() finds how many times a denominator multiplies before it gets the LCD
            numMultiplier(oneDenum,twoDenum);
            
            int i , p , x ,y;
            
            i = oneNum * firstMultiplier;
            p = twoNum * secondMultiplier;
            x = i + p;
            
            // this findLCD() method is for finding the Least Common Denominator
            y = findLCD(oneDenum,twoDenum);
            answerChecker(x,y);
            
        }
    }
    
    public static boolean simDesimChecker(int oneDenum,int twoDenom) {
        if(oneDenum == twoDenom) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    public static void answerChecker(int numerator, int denominator) {
        if(numerator < denominator) {
            System.out.println("the answer is: " + numerator + "/" + denominator);
        }else if (numerator > denominator) {
            int r = numerator % denominator;
            int i = numerator / denominator;
            System.out.println("the answer is: " + i + " and " + r + "/" + denominator);
        }else {
            System.out.println("the answer is: 1");
        }
    }
    
    public static int findLCD(int oneDenum, int twoDenum) {
        ArrayList<Integer> oneDenumAry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> twoDenumAry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        boolean matched = false;
        int multiplier = 1;
        int lcd = 0;

        while(!matched) {
            oneDenumAry.add(multiplier * oneDenum);
            twoDenumAry.add(multiplier * twoDenum); 
            for(int b : twoDenumAry) {
                for(int s : oneDenumAry) {
                    if(b == s) {
                        lcd = s;
                        matched = true;
                    }
                }
            }           
            multiplier++;
         }
        
        return lcd;
    }
    
    public static void numMultiplier(int oneDenum, int twoDenum) {
        ArrayList<Integer> oneDenumAry = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> twoDenumAry = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        
        boolean matched = false;
        int times = 1;
        while(!matched){
            oneDenumAry.add(times * oneDenum);
            twoDenumAry.add(times * twoDenum);
            for(int o :twoDenumAry) {
                for(int i : oneDenumAry) {
                    if(o == i) {
                        firstMultiplier = oneDenumAry.indexOf(i) + 1;
                        secondMultiplier = twoDenumAry.indexOf(o) + 1;
                        matched = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            times++;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean prog = true;
        
        while(prog) {
            System.out.println("=============================================================");
            System.out.println("============ FRACTION ADDTION and SUBTRACTION ===============");
            System.out.println("\n \n");
            
            System.out.println("1.) Addtion");
            System.out.println("2.) subtraction");
            System.out.println("3.) exit");
            System.out.println();
            
            System.out.print("choose an option: ");
            System.out.println();
            
            int o = keyboard.nextInt();
            
            if(o == 1) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.print("input first numerator:  ");
                
                int oneNum = keyboard.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("input first denominator:  ");
                
                int oneDenum = keyboard.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("input Second numerator:  ");
                
                int twoNum = keyboard.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println();
                System.out.print("input Second denominator:  ");
                
                int twoDenum = keyboard.nextInt();
                
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++");
                addFrac(oneNum,oneDenum,twoNum,twoDenum);
                System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++");
                System.out.println();
            }else {
                prog = false;
            }
            
        }
        
        keyboard.close();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

What I did was instead of saying nom and denom every time, I say commDeno and totNum. Code:

```
Public void AddFraction(int nom, int denom, int nom2, int denom2){

  Int comD, totNom;

  Nom = nom*denom2;
  Nom2 = nom2*denom;
  totNom =num+num2;
  comD = denom*denom2;
  Sysout(totNum + "/" +comD);

}
```